# Building parent project always recompiles all modules

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have a parent project with many child modules (it's a Netbeans platform application). The app builds and runs OK.

If I run `mvn compile` on the parent project twice, the 2nd time it's fast because Maven says "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date" for all the modules. Good.

If I run `mvn install` on the parent project twice, the 2nd time is as long as the 1st one because **only the first module is seen as "up to date"**. Maven detects changes for all the other modules and recompiles the source code.

I used `mvn -X` to try to understand what happens. For the 2nd module `org-jjazz-upgrade` I get this:

```
[DEBUG] New dependency detected: D:\JeromeDocs\NetBeansProjects\JJazzLab\modules\Utilities\target\org-jjazz-utilities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
```

`org-jjazz-utilities` is the first module which was up to date...

Is there a way to avoid this global recompilation with the `install` goal ?

Project source code with `mvn -X install` log (see `install.txt`) is available [here](https://github.com/jjazzboss/JJazzLabMaven).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's due to a maven-compiler-plugin bug documented [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-209), and has been unsolved for almost 10 years, despite many votes...

I just had to set `useIncrementalCompilation` to `false` in the plugin configuration (I use 3.10.0) and then it worked "normally". Quite counter-intuitive...